# How to access the Google Chrome prefs dictionary via WebDriver for Chrome?

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, watir, selenium-chromedriver

[Capabilities & ChromeOptions](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) is a page describing capabilities that can be used to customize and configure a Google Chrome session, using WebDriver for Chrome.

'prefs' is a dictionary in Google Chrome that stores the names of preference keys and their value.

I want to list all of the name-value pairs that exist in the prefs dictionary.

What Ruby code can I use to access (and pretty print) the 'prefs' which are stored as large dictionary?

Intent is to use particular prefs in setting browser prefs when starting a Watir session.